# Representing abbreviations in camel-cased class names

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions

I'm creating a C# library and am going to be prefix most of the public classes with the protocol they use (TCP, UDP, etc) and I came to a little dilemma: should it be `TCPXxxx` or `TcpXxxx`?

There doesn't seem to be a standard in the .NET framework (`IPAddress` versus `TcpClient`).

Which you would prefer when working with a library: `TCPXxxx` or `TcpXxxx`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be TcpXxxx, by the design guidelines.

In the design guidelines, 2 letter acronyms are capitalized, all others are pascal cased.

From *Framework Design Guidelines* by Cwalina and Abrams:

> - Do capitalize both charaters of two-character acronyms, exception the first word of a camel-cased identifier.

> ```
>     System.IO
>     public void StartIO(Stream ioStream)
> ```

> - Do capitalize only the first character of acronyms with three or more characters, except the first word of a camel cased identifier.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx) has an abbrieviated, shorter version of this.

Comment: I think you mean PascalCased, not camelCased.

Comment: @Reed: Do you have a link? Not that I don't believe you, but I'd like to read it.

Comment: @Samuel: I added it from the book itself... adding a link to msdn.

Comment: @Joel: Thanks for the note - just typed it wrong.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

I always like to imagine a theoretical process that converts WordsLikeThis to words-like-this, and imagine how the name in question would convert. Some examples:

TCPSocket -> t-c-p-socket
TcpSocket -> tcp-socket

Clearly the latter makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when it's a 2-character prefix, leave it uppercase (IPAddress) and when it's 3 characters or more, Pascal-case the prefix (TcpXxxx).

There are a few exceptions to this rule (e.g., if a prefix is a proper name that's uppercase).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is C# coding style but I prefer the [Python PEP 8 Style](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

> Note: When using abbreviations in CapWords, capitalize all the letters
>   of the abbreviation.  Thus HTTPServerError is better than
>   HttpServerError.

But when in Rome...consistent code is better which is why language style guides are a good idea.

Comment: @Daren Totally agreed, but I like to express it more aptly as, "Consistency over Perfectionism" to avoid antagonists implying incorrectness as the only alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider putting these classes in a namespace called "TCP". If you do so, then your function/class names in that namespace will get shorter and clearer and you won't have to worry about this issue at all.

Comment: That still has the problem with TCP vs. Tcp. And I want them as a prefix since I will be using terms like Client, Server, User, etc. I don't want someone to have to use a using alias to avoid a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I know in eclipse I can quickly specify a type by using just the capitals letters of the type name so I prefer to under-capitalise rather than over-capitalise... I don't know if VS can do the same but it is *fan-tastic*.